# How to show paginated text from a QTextDocument in QML?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qt-quick

I currently have a C++ class inheriting from `QQuickPaintedItem`. I use it to paint layouted, paginated richtext from a `QTextDocument` via `QTextDocument::drawContents` (or by directly calling its QTextDocumenLayout's `draw` method).

However, as stated in `QQuickPaintedItems` documentation, there are threading issues to be aware of:

> **Warning**: Extreme caution must be used when creating QObjects, emitting signals, starting timers and similar inside this function as these will have affinity to the rendering thread.

Specifically, in this case, `QTextDocumentLayoutPrivate` has timers which get started/stopped when `QTextDocumenLayout::draw` is called. Unfortunately, the `QTextDocument` and thus the timers lives in the qml main thread, while `paint` is called in the render thread, leading to messages like

> QBasicTimer::start: Timers cannot be started from another thread

While this doesn't affect the functionality of my application (so far), this is probably not a good thing™.

Therefore, my question is whether there is a better way to show the paginated text in QML (not necessarily involving `QQuickPaintedItem`).

Comment: What is your question: the question of the title or the last line of the content?

Comment: @eyllanesc: I changed the question's title hoping that the question is now clearer.

Answer (score 1):

For now I'm still using the `QQuickPaintedItem` and when `paint` is called I do the following:

- First check whether the `QTextDocument` has its affinity set to its current thread. If yes, I'll proceed as normal.
- Otherwise `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` is used to call a method which moves the document to the rendering thread, and calls `update` to trigger a repaint, which now works as the thread affinity is correct. At the end of `paint`, the `QTextDocument`'s thread affinity is set back to the original thread.

This works as far as I can tell (as in, no more warnings), but feels conceptually rather wrong.

Comment: In the invoked method, how do you access the rendering thread in order to move the document to it?